# Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios5

How can I add the black bar in the above of keyboard when it appears.
I mean the bar when you click on the search box of Safari appears above keyboard and let you search on the page?
And How I can customize the bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called an accessory view. [This tutorial](http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html) should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It is accessory view.

you can add like this

`textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar`

and you need to add it in textfield delegate methods

if you need a good tutorial one this, please refer below link

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/27/keyboard-tutorial-part-3-add-a-toolbar-to-the-keyboard/